# How to do OR search

Tags: php, mongodb, find, partial

I want to search for a partial first and last name match - for example in sql

```
f_name LIKE J%   OR  l_name LIKE S%
```

would match John Smith or John Henry or  Harry Smith .

I am assuming I may need to use the "$or" operator,

I have this so far that I believe is doing the LIKE % part properly, but I believe it is doing an "AND" search (meaning it searches for  f_name LIKE J%  AND  l_name LIKE S% so it would only match John Smith):

```
$name1="J";
$name2="S";
$cursor = $this->clientCollection->find(array('f_name' => new MongoRegex('/^'.$name1.'/i'), 'l_name' => new MongoRegex('/^'.$name2.'/i') ));
```

Note: This will match containing as in    %J%

```
MongoRegex('/'.$name1.'/i')
```

This will match starts with (notice the added ^) as in   J%

```
MongoRegex('/^'.$name1.'/i')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$or` takes an array of clauses, so you basically just need to wrap another array around your current query:

```
array('$or' => array(
    array('f_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$name1.'/i')), 
    array('l_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$name2.'/i'))
));
```

Edit: the previous example missed an inner set of `array()` calls.

The original, wrong, example that I posted looked like this:

```
array('$or' => array(
    'f_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$name1.'/i'), 
    'l_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$name2.'/i')
));
```

This is a valid query, but not a useful one. Essentially, the `f_name` and `l_name` query parts are still ANDed together, so the `$or` part is useless (it's only getting passed one query, so it's the same as just running that query by itself).

As for the alternative you mentioned in your comment, that one doesn't work because the outermost array in a query has to be an associative array. The confusion arises because Mongo's query syntax is JSON-like and uses a mixture of objects and arrays, but both of those structures are represented in PHP by arrays. The PHP Mongo driver basically converts PHP associative arrays to JSON objects (`{ ... }`), and "normal" PHP arrays to JSON arrays (`[ ... ]`).

The practical upshot is that "normal" PHP arrays are generally only valid when inside an associative array, like when specifying multiple values for a field. The following example from the [PHP Mongo manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php) shows a valid usage of a "normal" array in a query:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("awards" => array('$in' => array("gold", "copper"))));
```

Comment: This works, but I was just wondering why the inner set of array calls? The original code works, it returns records as an AND.   I tried using changing the code to  $cursor = $this->clientCollection->find(array(array('f_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$name1.'/i')),array('l_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$name2.'/i')) )); and it does not work, but it does in your case with the '$or'.

Comment: I've tried to explain what's going on here. Unfortunately, all those PHP `array()`s can make it pretty hard to tell what's going on in a Mongo query in PHP, especially at a glance.